# This codes can't check NoResultException

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

This is the Code I was made. It shouldn't get and enter to NoResultException, but it doesn't as expected. There is an unused data. I try to print out, here is the output : "[ ]"

```
private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {            
        int row = tableDataRangka.getSelectedRow();
        String idRangka = tableDataRangka.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        System.out.println( relasiRumahkayuRangkaDAO.getRelasiByIdRangka(idRangka).toString() );
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        // Doing something..        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MasterDataProjectUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of method "getRelasiByIdRangka" :

```
public List<RelasiRumahKayuRangka> getRelasiByIdRangka(String idRangka) throws Exception{
    initEntityManager();
    List<RelasiRumahKayuRangka> rrDrs = new ArrayList<>();
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("RelasiRumahKayuRangka.findByIdRangka");
    q.setParameter("idRangka", idRangka);
    rrDrs.addAll(q.getResultList());
    closeEntityManager();
    return rrDrs;
}
```

And this one is the JPA query, findByIdRangka :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "RelasiRumahKayuRangka.findByIdRangka", query = "SELECT r FROM RelasiRumahKayuRangka r WHERE r.relasiRumahKayuRangkaPK.idRangka = :idRangka"),
```

Do you guys know the solution, so the code can be catched by NoResultException ?

Comment: the code "relasiRumahkayuRangkaDAO.getRelasiByIdRangka(idRangka)" should be catched by noResultException. I had filled the idRangka with the data which doesn't include in database.

Comment: Try throwing `noResultException` from somewhere, not just `Exception`. AS it is right now, that exception is not being thrown by anything.

Comment: Ok, i'll try, besides it usually works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code. if the result set is empty then list will also be empty.
Make use of that situation and throw a desired exception.

In your `getRelasiByIdRangka(String idRangka)` add following changes.

```
public List<RelasiRumahKayuRangka>
   getRelasiByIdRangka( String idRangka ) throws Exception {
    initEntityManager();
    // rest of the code here
    // ...

    // check if some results are found or not
    if( rrDrs.isEmpty() ) { // or ( rrDrs.size() == 0 )
       throw new NoResultException( "No results found" );
    } // if empty

    // this should be a filled in list
    return rrDrs;
} // end of method
```